# Netlogo: how can I use contract net protocol in my model

Tags: netlogo

Good morning people,
At the moment I have a template in netlogo that allows to visualize routes of deliveries in houses created randomly.

```
globals[route-vector]
breed [carr car]
breed [spare spares]
breed [hous housess]
breed [spawns spawn]
carr-own [ route route-counter spawn-target target route-complete?]
spare-own[ route route-counter spawn-target target route-complete?]

to setup
clear-all
create-carros
create-casas
path
reset-ticks
end

to create-carros
create-carr 2 [ set color green ]
ask carr  [
set size 1.5
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set route-counter 0
set target nobody
set route []
set route-complete? false
pd
]
end

to create-carspare
create-spare 1 [ set color blue ]
ask spare  [
set size 1.5
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
set route-counter 0
set target nobody
set route []
set route-complete? false
pd
]
end

to create-casas
create-hous 5 [ set color red ]
ask hous  [
set shape "house"
set size 1.5
setxy random-xcor random-ycor
]
end

to path
set route-vector [4 7 6 3 5 0 1 1 0 1]

let houses sublist route-vector 0 (length route-vector / 2 )
let carlist sublist route-vector (length route-vector / 2 ) (length route-
vector)

(foreach carlist houses
[ [the-car the-house] ->
  ask car the-car [
    set route lput ( housess the-house ) route
  ]
]
)
ask carr [
hatch 1 [
  set breed spawns
  ht
]
set spawn-target one-of other turtles-here with [
  xcor = [xcor] of myself
]
]
end

to go

ask carr with [ not route-complete? ] [

if route = [] [
  set target spawn-target
]

if target = nobody [
  set target item route-counter route
]

face target
ifelse distance target > 1 [
  fd 1
] [
  move-to target
   ifelse target != spawn-target [
    set route-counter route-counter + 1
  ] [
    set route-complete? true
  ]
  set target nobody
 ]
 if route-counter > length route - 1 [
  set route-counter 0
  set target spawn-target

  ]
  ]
  tick
  end
```

I thought about using a broken or crash switch, and a slider with how many maximum home deliveries per car.

in my go procedure I put:

```
 ask carr with [failure?] [
 if ticks = 25 [ask one-of carr [set crash? TRUE]
  set target spawn-target
```

Assuming the maximum deliveries per car are 3 and as one or more houses will not be visited because of the car that stopped, I put a reschedule button:

```
 to reschedule
 ask one-of spare with [not route-complete?] ; How do I make the reservation 
 car take the route of the car that stopped?
[
  set target [car route that stopped]
]
set target spawn-target
end
```

I need some help in my reschedule bottom. if a car stops, and does not finish the route, the reserve car should take over the houses that are missing to visit

Thanks in advance for your understanding, and if you can help, I was grateful.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? If you want to stop a car after a certain number of ticks, then you do something like `if ticks = 25 [ ask one-of cars [die] ]`. If you want to stop after visiting 3 houses, you do something different. If your problem is about passing information from one car to another, then you set your new car's relevant variables to the variables of the old car. As you can see, you need to tell us exactly what it is you want to code. And you should also show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you in advance for your response. Using ticks to stop a car would be a good option.
But my problem would be to get the cars to negotiate with each other, who would visit the missing homes for the car that stopped. Use distance as a decision factor? but how to code? that is, if the car in reserve was closer to the missing homes, would he, or would one of the cars visit ... I do not know how to codify these possibilities and the agents make the decision ....

Comment: All of these options can be coded. You need to decide what exactly you want coded and then we can help you with how to code it.

Comment: That said, I will put in a switch to model crash, which identifies that after 25 ticks (slider) one car stops.
When some task breaks, the problem should divide into subtasks with the hypotheses that I said:
1 hypothesis could be to use the car in reserve.
2 hypothesize to use the car that has not stopped.
How to make the manager choose the best hypothesis? by the distance between them? if so, how to reactivate the model and finish all deliveries?

Comment: Sorry but sometimes I can not explain it well, but the idea is, Crash one of the cars, recognize the problem, announce what is missing, bid the 2 possibilities for the agents to choose, and choose the best one. I do not know how to create this dynamic

Comment: How would a human being do it? That is, what calculation would the human make for each option? You can't tell a computer how to do something that you don't already know how to do.

Comment: I understand @JenB, but this problem dynamics can only be more or less in theory. However, I made some modifications to my question. If you can guide me it was excellent.

Comment: @JenB, Sorry to bother you again, but I need your help. Initially I did not explain the problem very well, but I think the changes I made in the matter are already clearer. I appreciate your understanding.

Comment: The problem is that you are asking us to write the code, which is a lot of work. StackOverflow is to help fix code you have written, or sometimes to write small pieces of code that do a specific task. You are asking for several tasks that you haven't even attempted.

Comment: I did not know where to start, and so I tried to create a problem idea with many requirements. But it was complicating for you and especially for me.
I tried something new, however @JenB , help me in my bottom reschedule.
I need to use, or the car in reserve or the car that has not stopped and assign the route of the missing homes. If you can help me, I thank you immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you are asking, you have a car that has crashed and want to pass on the content of one of its variables to the spare car. The car that is crashed has the variable crash? set to TRUE, but I can't see from your code how you define a car to be the spare car. But it's probably something like this.

```
ask cars
[ <doing whatever they do>
  if <conditions for crash>
  [ set crash? TRUE
    ask one-of cars with [spare?]
    [ set spare? FALSE
      set target [target] of myself
    ]
    stop
  ]
]
```

Comment: yes, in two cars I create, one of them will stop, because the cars have the variable crash? i put in go procedure
I define the spare care in my setup, but I need the spare car to take the houses that have not been visited. thanks @JenB

Comment: The code `set target [target] of myself` passes the contents of the variable named target from the crashed car to the spare car. You can do this for all the variables you need to have the spare car take over the route.

Comment: Thanks @JenB, i really appreciate your help.
Cheers!